# How to start passenger nginx, error : Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby, rubygems

Application is broken in production mode and getting below error while restarting passenger and nginx.

```
[ agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:338 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:400 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ ServerKit/Server.h:453 ]: [LoggerAdminServer] Shutdown finished
[ agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:425 ]: PassengerAgent logger shutdown finished
[ ServerKit/Server.h:453 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ ServerKit/Server.h:453 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ ServerKit/Server.h:453 ]: [AdminServer] Shutdown finished
[ agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:724 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 19431, application /public#default
[ agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:724 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 19440, application /public#default
[ agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:1255 ]: Starting PassengerAgent watchdog...
[ agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:883 ]: Starting PassengerAgent server...
[ agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:232 ]: PassengerAgent server running in multi-application mode.
[ agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:637 ]: PassengerAgent server online, PID 19637
[ agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:431 ]: Starting PassengerAgent logger...
[ agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:312 ]: PassengerAgent logger online, PID 19645
[ agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:868 ]: PassengerAgent server shutdown finished
```

Please help me out.

**Updated:**

Command to restart Nginx server:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Command to restart Passenger server:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Comment: Please provide the command(s) you are using to restart the services.

Comment: Updated question, please check @Gene

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to process taking lots of time itself while running. Due to which passenger was unable to serve.

**I replaced passenger application server with thin server. I started multiple instances of thin. Now everything is perfect up and running.**

Thanks.